# Make the default end time of an appointment be one hour

Tags: calendar

I am trying to change the default settings of the end time of any appointment made in a SharePoint calendar appointment to be one hour.  I found something on the Internet that I needed to paste a jquery script into the content source editor of a content editor web part added to the newform.aspx page.  I do not know scripts at all, and tried to pasted what they posted but that did not change the default time to be one hour later.  The default start time and end time are currently exactly the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a link to the script you found?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Comment: I'll disagree with "closed as too localized", I was searching for just this information, and am disappointed the question was not allowed to run its natural course.

Answer (score 1):

As confusing as the scripts might be, they are considerably easier than what it would take to force that behavior via custom field controls.  I suggest you track down someone who knows jQuery well and work with them to set up the script.  It shouldn't be too difficult though.